Google Cloud Firestore - Can no longer see the storage size in Google Cloud - App Engine - Quotas
I used to follow up the storage size of my Firestore databases on the 'Google Cloud - App Engine - Quotas' page. But since a few days, the information is gone.
Have tried to find out if the information has moved, but cant find it. Where ever I look I just see information on reads, writes and deletes etc.
Looking at the documentation, it sounds like the information should be there.
Does anyone know where to find it?
Or can there be some error on my databases? Do not experience any, but I quess there can be some anyway.
I have used the documentation on Firestore and Google Cloud. Tried Google as well. No luck ...
